# Does LEGO Digital Designer include part 4539880?

Tags: technic, ldd, gears

Does anyone know if LEGO Digital Designer includes the [part 4539880](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64179&ccName=4539880#T=P&C=86) (often used for housing differentials) ?

[image: part 4539880]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but only one color choice of light bluish gray is available in the default mode.

[image]

Comment: If you switch to the "Digital Designer Extended" mode, you can choose any color for any part.

Comment: MindS1, my friend, you've just blown... my mind.  I never knew there was an  Extended Mode, and hell, a clickable tab available at program launch.  THANK YOU!!!